# Cross-references in PDF

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown, pdflatex

I'm writing a book in Rstudio using Bookdown. I had to take a break and suddenly none of my cross-references work in the pdf version of the document although they still work in HTML. Before, everything was okay, but now no bib or equation or figure references work! I looked for an explanation and it may be due to pandoc version. I don't know what to do :frowning: Can anyone help me, please?

I don't know what to try since all works when the output is html.
The only changes were different versions meanwhile updated.